# Move images in every div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML code:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-1.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-2.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-3.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
```

I need to move each image from "source" to "destination" in each div-"block".

When I'm trying the code:

```
$j('.block .source img').each(function () {
        $j(this).detach().appendTo('.block > .destination');
    });
```

I'm getting all three images in each div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`.closest(SELECTOR)`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find `closest` parent element of the `ELEMENT`

```js
var $j = $;
$j('.block .source img').each(function() {
  $j(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.block').find('.destination'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="destination"></div>
  <div class="source">
    <img src="/img-1.png" alt="test">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="destination"></div>
  <div class="source">
    <img src="/img-2.png" alt="test">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="destination"></div>
  <div class="source">
    <img src="/img-3.png" alt="test">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the HTML, you will see that the images are now inside the `.destination` divs:

```js
$('.block').find('.source').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var img = that.children().clone();
  that.empty();
  that.closest('.block').find('.destination').append(img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-1.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-2.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-3.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$j('.block .source img').each(function() {
  $j(this).appendTo( $(this).parent().prev() );
});
```

You need to use `this` to refer to the image being looped over, and there's no need to use detach() with appendTo() as appendTo() will handle the moving.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fj9tqrwv/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".block").each(function(){
    var html = $(this).find(".source").html();
  $(this).find(".source").empty();
  $(this).find(".destination").html(html);
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/40x85u7b/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.block').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  //find the image is source and append it to the destination.  append will do the detach for you
  $this.find('.source img').appendTo($this.find('.destination'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-1.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-2.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="destination"></div>
    <div class="source"><img src="/img-3.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>
```